# Why is Spring Boot so slow in comparison to Node.js and Electron?

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, electron

I was working on converting a trading applications API calls to Spring boot in order to leverage IB's TWS API. I figured I may as well keep it all in one application. Initially, I was issuing my requests through Angular 2, leveraging Electron. However, when I converted to Spring Boot, I noticed what took a second to return in with Angular and Electron, took upwards of almost seven seconds. I'm having a hard time believing that Java is this slow in comparison to JavaScript. I'm assuming at this point there's a much faster way to do what I'm attempting to do in Java. Any help would be appreciated. Again, I'm simply looking for advice on how to speed things up here, if at all possible.

```
  //Spring Boot Service Layer ---- 7 seconds :-o Seriously....

  public List<QuoteResponse> getGapUps(PriceParams p) {

    GapUpFilter guf = new GapUpFilter(p);
    int payloadSize = 200;
    StringBuilder payLoad = new StringBuilder();
    String stocks = this.getAllStocks();
    String[] sArr = stocks.split(",");
    LinkedList<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>( Arrays.asList(sArr));
    List<QuoteResponse> qrList = new ArrayList<QuoteResponse>();

    while (ll.size() > 0) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < payloadSize && ll.size() > 0) {
            String stock = ll.pop();
            if (stock != null && stock.length() > 0 && ll.size() > 1) {
                payLoad.append(stock);
                payLoad.append(",");
            } 
            if (stock != null && stock.length() > 0 && ll.size() == 1) {
                payLoad.append(stock);
            } 
            i++;
        }
        QuoteResponseWrapper qrw = this.getPrice(payLoad.toString());
        QuoteResponse qr = guf.filterQuote(qrw.getQuoteResponse());
        if (qr.getResult().length > 0) {
            qrList.add(qr);
        }
        payLoad = new StringBuilder();
    }
    return qrList;
}


// Angular, Node.js with Electron - instantaneous

geMarketGaps(stocks: string, pFilter: PriceParams) {
this.securityService.getGaps(stocks).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(lst => {

  for (let i = 0; i < lst.quoteResponse.result.length; i++) {
    try {

      const ppq = new PrePostQuote();
      ppq.symbol = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].symbol;

      try { ppq.pclose = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].regularMarketPrice.raw; } catch (e) {console.log(ppq.symbol, e); }
      try { ppq.cprice = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].regularMarketPrice.raw; } catch (e) {console.log(ppq.symbol, e);  }
      try { ppq.regularMarketPrice = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].regularMarketPrice.raw; } catch (e) { }
      try { ppq.ask = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].ask.raw; } catch (e) {console.log(ppq.symbol, e);  }
      try { ppq.bid = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].bid.raw; } catch (e) {console.log(ppq.symbol, e);  }
      try { ppq.shortName = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].shortName; } catch (e) {console.log(ppq.symbol, e);  }
      try { ppq.sharesOutstanding = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].sharesOutstanding.fmt; } catch (e) { ppq.sharesOutstanding = '0'; }
      try { ppq.regularMarketVolume = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].regularMarketVolume.raw; } catch (e) {console.log(ppq.symbol, e);  }
      try { ppq.averageDailyVolume3Month = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].averageDailyVolume3Month.raw; } catch (e) {
        console.log(ppq.symbol, e); }
      try { ppq.epsTrailingTwelveMonths = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].epsTrailingTwelveMonths.raw; } catch (e) {
        console.log(ppq.symbol, e);  }
      try { ppq.priceToBook = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].priceToBook.raw; } catch (e) {console.log(ppq.symbol, e);  }
      try { ppq.askSize = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].askSize.raw; } catch (e) {console.log(ppq.symbol, e);  }
      try { ppq.bidSize = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].bidSize.raw; } catch (e) {console.log(ppq.symbol, e);  }
      try { ppq.fullExchangeName = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].fullExchangeName; } catch (e) {console.log(ppq.symbol, e);  }
      try { ppq.regularMarketDayHigh = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].regularMarketDayHigh.raw; } catch (e) {console.log(ppq.symbol, e);  }
      try { ppq.regularMarketDayLow = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].regularMarketDayHigh.raw; } catch (e) {console.log(ppq.symbol, e);  }
      try { ppq.regularMarketOpen = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].regularMarketOpen.raw; } catch (e) {console.log(ppq.symbol, e);  }
      try { ppq.shortPotential = ppq.getShortPotential(1.2); } catch (e) { }

      try {
        ppq.marketState = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].marketState;
        // console.log('Market State: => ' + ppq.symbol, ppq.marketState);
      } catch (e) { }

      if (!ppq.marketState) {
        continue;
      }

      try { ppq.regularMarketChangePercent = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].regularMarketChangePercent.raw; } catch (e) { }
      try { ppq.pctraw = ppq.regularMarketChangePercent; } catch (e) { console.log(e); }

      if (ppq.marketState === 'REGULAR') {
        this.marketState = 'Reg Mkt';
      }

      if ((ppq.marketState === 'POST')
      && lst.quoteResponse.result[i].postMarketPrice) {
        try { ppq.cprice = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].postMarketPrice.raw; } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        try { ppq.postMarketChangePercent
          = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].postMarketChangePercent.raw; } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        try { ppq.pctgain = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].postMarketChangePercent.fmt; } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        try { ppq.pctraw = ppq.postMarketChangePercent; } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        this.marketState = 'Post Mkt';
      }

      if ((ppq.marketState === 'PREPRE' || ppq.marketState === 'POSTPOST'
      || ppq.marketState === 'CLOSED') && lst.quoteResponse.result[i].postMarketPrice) {
        try { ppq.cprice = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].postMarketPrice.raw; } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        try { ppq.postMarketPrice = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].postMarketPrice.raw; } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        try { ppq.postMarketChangePercent = ppq.getPrePrePctChange(); } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        try { ppq.pctgain = ppq.getPrePrePctChange().toFixed(2) + '%'; } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        try {
          ppq.pctraw = ppq.postMarketChangePercent;
          if ( ppq.pctraw > 5) {
            console.log(ppq.symbol + ' is greater than five percent');
          }
        } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        this.marketState = 'Post Mkt';
      }

      if (ppq.marketState === 'PRE' && lst.quoteResponse.result[i].preMarketPrice) {
        try { ppq.cprice = parseFloat(lst.quoteResponse.result[i].preMarketPrice.raw); } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        try { ppq.preMarketChangePercent
           = parseFloat(lst.quoteResponse.result[i].preMarketChangePercent.raw); } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        try { ppq.pctgain = lst.quoteResponse.result[i].preMarketChangePercent.fmt; } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        try { ppq.pctraw = ppq.preMarketChangePercent; } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
        this.marketState = 'Pre Mkt';
      }

      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      if (ppq.cprice >= pFilter.minPrice && ppq.cprice <= pFilter.maxPrice) {

        if (ppq.pctraw > 0
          && this.activeFilter === 'Market Movers'
          && (ppq.marketState === 'PRE' || ppq.marketState === 'PREPRE' || ppq.marketState === 'POST' || ppq.marketState === 'POSTPOST'
          || ppq.marketState === 'CLOSED'
        )
        ) {
          if (ppq.postMarketChangePercent >= pFilter.percent || ppq.preMarketChangePercent >= pFilter.percent ) {
            this.quotes.push(ppq);
          }
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if (ppq.pctraw > 0 && this.activeFilter === 'Pct Gainers') {
          if (ppq.regularMarketChangePercent >= pFilter.percent) {
            this.quotes.push(ppq);
          }
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if (ppq.pctraw < 0 && this.activeFilter === 'Market Losers'
        && (ppq.marketState === 'PRE' || ppq.marketState === 'PREPRE' || ppq.marketState === 'POST'
        || ppq.marketState === 'POSTPOST' || ppq.marketState === 'CLOSED')
      ) {
          if (ppq.postMarketChangePercent <= (pFilter.percent * -1) || ppq.preMarketChangePercent <= (pFilter.percent * -1)) {
            this.quotes.push(ppq);
          }
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if (ppq.pctraw < 0 && this.activeFilter === 'Pct Losers') {
          if (ppq.regularMarketChangePercent <= (pFilter.percent * -1)) {
            this.quotes.push(ppq);
          }
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      }


    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }

  }
  this.recordsProcessed++;
  this.securityService.progressStart.next(this.recordsProcessed);

  if (this.recordCount === this.recordsProcessed) {
    this.showRecs = true;
  }

}, error => {
  this.recordsProcessed++;
  this.securityService.progressStart.next(this.recordsProcessed);
  if (this.recordCount === this.recordsProcessed) {
    this.showRecs = true;
  }
});

}
```

Comment: What does your debugging (or profiler..!) tell you about where the time is being used..?

Comment: I didn't check that, but I will in a bit.

Comment: After a closer look, here is what I found in profiler:

Hot Spot                                                                                      Milliseconds
java.lang.Thread.run                                                              4657.485
com.vicentex.jdai.controllers.ResearchController.getGapUps     4286.102
com.vicentex.jdai.services.SkyWalker.getGapUps                      4286.102
com.vicentex.jdai.services.SkyWalker.getPrice                      4206.546
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity      4019.258

Comment: @LeoWilliams Seems like almost all of the time is used for remote communication (RestTemplate.getForEntity). Consider to add connection pool to avoid expensive connection creations. Also the above problem is really good for multithreading since it is almost entirely IO bound.
Also generally speaking the startup and first requests for a Java application will be slower than in case of JavaScript. This is due to JVM requires lots of time for initialization, also during the first requests Java will run in interpreted mode (gathering information what to compile) that takes significantly longer

Comment: I'm currently looking at CompletableFuture to see if I can duplicate the asynchronous behavior in Java that's inherent OOTB with Node.js. After reviewing the Java documentation, I have some ideas about how to restructure this. I'll post the resulting code if I'm able to see a drastic improvement.

Comment: CompleteableFuture worked beautifully! I can pull quotes for the entire exchange is the same time from I did in Node.js. In fact, it was even faster. Almost, 90,000 lines of JSON. I used CompletableFuture in conjunction with CopyOnWriteArrayList to store the data with each payload, keeping track of the invocations similarly to how I did in Node.js, using a recordCount and recordsProcessed variable. In the rest controller, I used a while loop with Thread.sleep(10) until recordCount was equivalent to recordsProcessed. It happened so fast, I actually had to put a delay in the quote calls. Java++

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is interested, CompleteableFuture was the solution I employed. I was able to literally pull down over 7MB of JSON in a fraction of the time, literally all quote data for all stock exchanges. By making each request utilize a new thread, the queries ran in parallel, so fast in fact, I had to inject a slight delay in the calls, which laughably is what consumes most of the time. I have to admit, I was of the school of thought that Node.js was certainly faster due to REPL and its non-blocking architecture. However, after taking a deeper dive into the Rabbit hole of Java's multi-threaded abyss, I would strongly caution against such claims.

```
@Async
public void loadPriceQuotes(String stocks) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    this.currentRecord++;
    System.out.println(this.currentRecord + " => " + this.recordCount);

    URLUtility urlUtil = new URLUtility();
    RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();

    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<QuoteResponseWrapper>() {
        @Override
        public QuoteResponseWrapper get() {

            String url = urlUtil.getPriceURL(stocks);
            ResponseEntity<QuoteResponseWrapper> response = rt.getForEntity(url, QuoteResponseWrapper.class);

            for (Quote q: response.getBody().getQuoteResponse().getResult()) {
                SkyWalker.stockQuotes.add(q);
            }

            return response.getBody();
        }
    },executor);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Yup. It's the difference between serial, synchronous processing and concurrent, async processing. Check out Play framework if you have time. But in my experience even with Java8 Futures Node.js is still slightly faster because all it's low-level operations are async by default. Java on the other hand needs work-arounds for things like database access because almost everything expects to be synchronous. Also, the nature of creating data in javascript is much more lightweight than object creation in Java - just compare memory usage